# Let a link become "active" without class add/remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change a link to "active" without add/removing a class? The problem i´ve got is, that my other script will not work if the "a"-tag will be changed for example to "a.active".

So this way works for the link, but not for my other script ;(, because a class will be add and remove.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.mydiv a').click(function(){
            $('.mydiv .active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can anybody help me?

***UPDATE 2***
Thats the script I work with:
http://jsfiddle.net/7n2d4b44/2/

Comment: why wont your other script work if anchor has .active class?

Comment: It works once, but if I click the same link again the script dont work anymore. So, if I remove the link-script from the top, my other script works fine, no matter how often I click the same link. So I think the script get a problem with the class add/remove?

Comment: @Snatch Then fix that script. If you need an active class on the element then there's not really any way to work around that.

Comment: I have add the script at the top now, maybe someone can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to hold data, don't use class names as data. You can use the [jQuery .data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to get the value of a data-* attribute.

```js
var sliding = $('.sliding_div');
var divWords = $('.sliding_div p');

$('.links a').click(function () {
    //pass .data the name after the `data-` part in the attribute name
    var c = '.' + $(this).data("filter"); // get name to filter classes and make it as a CSS selector
    
    divWords.hide().filter(c).show(); // hide all words, 
    // filter to get the ones with class like the clicked link
    // show the filtered ones

    //You could move this to its own handler
    //$(".links a.close).click(...)
    c === '.close' ? sliding.hide() : sliding.show();
    // if c is .close show the sliding_div else hide it
  
    $(".links .active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.links {
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
}
.sliding_div {
    padding:10px;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    background-color:#ccc;
    display:none;
}
.sliding_div div {
    display:none;
}
.active{
    color:#F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links"> 
    <a href="#" data-filter='one'>Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter='two'>Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter='three'>Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter='close'>Close</a>
</div>

<div class="sliding_div">
    <p class='one two three'>House</p>
    <p class='one two three'>Cat</p>
    <p class='one'>Dog</p>
    <p class='three'>Car</p>
    <p class='one two'>Man</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats for me the perfect solution - big thx!! An thx to all other guys!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS pseudo-class I think like:

```
a:active { color: lime }
```

More info [CSS :active pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

Comment: This will only style the link if the user is actively holding mouse down on the anchor which is probably not what OP is wanting. Setting an element to have an `active` class tends to be used to show the user that that item is the currently shown item on the page i.e. setting a menu item to active to show its the current page.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(this).addClass('active');` should append so the element should have 2 classes. The other class should not be removed. You can double check.

In your case, it could be that your function to access the other class is not coded correctly

Comment: I have add the script at the top now - maybe y can fix it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7n2d4b44/8/ -- done. a little hacky but it works. ideally you want to store the links in an array and iterate through

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes, but you should now be able to add your code to use the active class, without worrying about this bit...

**css**

```
.links {
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
}
.sliding_div {
    padding:10px;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.sliding_div p {
    display:none;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="links">
    <a href="#" data-link='one'>Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-link='two'>Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" data-link='three'>Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Close</a>
</div>
<div class="sliding_div">
    <p class='one two three'>House</p>
    <p class='one two three'>Cat</p>
    <p class='one'>Dog</p>
    <p class='three'>Car</p>
    <p class='one two'>Man</p>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var sliding = $(".sliding_div");
var divWords = $(".sliding_div p");

$(".links a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    divWords.hide();
    sliding.find("." + $(this).data("link")).show();
});
```

**jsfiddle example...**

http://jsfiddle.net/7n2d4b44/7/

Comment: I feel like this would benefit greatly from some explanation about what you changed and why. Then again, maybe they don't care about learning and will just be happy that they have some working code.

Comment: Maybe some users only copy it, but i think its also a good way to see the script live - so thx to archer too!